# Rails 3 How To Access Value From Within A Partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm rendering a partial with this:

```
<%= render 'fields', f: f %>
```

Then within `_fields.html.erb`, I have a line like this:

```
<%= f.text_field :energy %>
```

Which works fine, it renders a text field with the correct value.  But how can I directly output the value of that variable?  If I try something like:

```
<%= :energy %>
```

It just renders the text `energy`.  I want to output the value to go into a datafield of a div for use by a jquery component.  So how can I just render the current value of the `:energy` field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

f.object accesses the object that is being looped in the builder.

Answer (score 0):

With `text_field :energy` you just create a HTML input field with `name="text"`.

When using `<%= :energy %>`: Where does your variable come from?

Answer (score 0):

`:energy` is a Ruby symbol, which is a text value that Ruby allocates memory for and then resuses every time you need the text "energy", as opposed to `"energy"`, which Ruby allocates a different memory block for every time you use it.  But, since a symbol is still just a text value, `<%= :energy %>` just outputs the text "energy".